# Cygwin Command Substitution not Working

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin

I am trying to trouble shoot a problem I am seeing when running bash commands in Cygwin.

I am trying to assign the CLang version from a text file to a variable. If I run this in Cygwin:

`$ (sed -n 1p "$CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE" | sed 's/\s//g')`

I get this output (which is exactly what I want):

`14.10.25903`

Now, if I try and assign this to a variable it doesn't work. Here is what I am trying:

`$ CLANGC2_VERSION=$(sed -n 1p "$CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE" | sed 's/\s//g')`

but when I inspect or print the variable, it is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing double quotes? Try `CLANGC2_VERSION="$(sed -n 1p "$CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE" | sed 's/\s//g')"`

Comment: not able to reproduce the issue when I tried on my Linux machine.. please post first two lines of input file.. also you don't need two calls to sed.. try `sed -n '1s/\s//gp'`

Comment: @BernatPedrolVozmediano double quotes results in the same issue.

@Sundeep The file contents is `14.10.259031`

Comment: What happens if you just run `TVAR=$( echo "test" ) ; echo $TVAR
`?  Does anything get stored in TVAR?

Comment: @PatrickKelly Yes, 'test' gets stored in TVAR.

Comment: @PatrickKelly It's worth noting that if I remove the seconds sed, it works. I.e:

`$ CLANGC2_VERSION=$(sed -n 1p "$CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE")`

But I really do need the second sed for whitespace removal

Comment: check with `od -c $CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE` if there is any unusual character in the file

Comment: @matzeri contents looks OK. `0000000   1   4   .   1   0   .   2   5   9   0   3
0000013`

Comment: There is no space character. Why you need the second sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there is a known 'Big List of Dodgy Apps' (BLODA) which can interfere with Cygwin and bash.

The discussion I found is here: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2017-07/msg00197.html
The BLODA list is here: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Turns out my AntiVirus is on the list.

I've removed the AV and now the commands work. There must be some low-level stuff going with the AV that causes it to fail.

Comment: Just a curiosity. Which AV was ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks to get the desired results.

```
CLANGC2_VERSION=`(sed -n 1p "$CLANGC2_VERSION_FILE" | sed 's/\s//g')`
```

Comment: I've tried backticks, which is equivalent to `$()`, but I get the same issue.

Comment: Interesting.  It works fine on my installation (both ways, actually).  Is there anything atypical about your Cygwin setup/environment?

Comment: I guess the only thing that is different is that I am downloading Cygwin into a build tools directory as part of a setup script. I download the Cygwin setup using powershell and then launch the Cygwin setup, passing it a required packages file.